# retreive XML value that is empty

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml doc I am reading in java, and all is fine until I get to a record with an empty tag.  The first row comes back fine, it is the second row, where the Usability is not set, that the app errors out with the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at tableDisplay.tableApplication.getValue(tableApplication.java:156)
```

I have tried to put a check like

```
 if(node.getNodeValue() == null)
     return "";
 else
    return node.getNodeValue();
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.  What am I missing here?

```
<DATA>
        <ROW>
                <Id>a0550000008zYHPAA2</CertId>
                <AddonId>a0550000008zYHPAA2</AddonId>
                <CareSetting>Office</CareSetting>
                <Usability>4</Usability>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
                <Id>a0550000008zYHPAA2</CertId>
                <AddonId>a0550000008zYHPAA2</AddonId>
                <CareSetting>Office</CareSetting>
                <Usability></Usability>
        </ROW>
</DATA>


     private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
         NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
         Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);


        return node.getNodeValue();  // line 156

     }
```

Comment: what code do you have at `tableApplication.java:156`?

Answer (score 0):

solved it by doing return element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getTextContent(); in place on line 156. Then, elswhere, if i need to convert that string to a int/long/etc, I check to see if it is equal to "";